# Use selected dropdown option as variable for use in node.js Kmeans function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, k-means

I need to retrieve the selected dropdown value from this code block in a .hbs file...

```
<div class="section-color">
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-md center-block">
    <h2>{{survey.name}} Cluster</h2>
    <p>This cluster was calculated using kmeans with k = {{k}}</p>
    <p> Change cluster to: </p>
     <select class="form-control" name='kvalue' id="kvalue" value='{{form.kvalue}}'>
         <option value=2>2</option>
         <option value=3>3</option>
         <option value=4>4</option>
         <option value=5>5</option>
         <option value=6>6</option>
         <option value=7>7</option>
         <option value=8>8</option>
         <option value=9>9</option>
         <option value=10>10</option>
    </select>
    <a class='btn btn-default' href='/survey/{{survey._id}}/results'>Clusterize!</a>
</div>
```

.. and use it as the 'k' value in this node.js routes file:

```
async function renderViewResults (req, res, next) {
const { id } = req.params;
try {
    let { survey, questions } = await fetchSurveyInfo(id);
    const responses = await Response.find({ surveyId: survey._id });
    const userResponse = responses.filter(res => res.userId.toString() === req.user._id.toString())[0];
    const userAnswerSequence = !isNil(userResponse);

    if (userResponse) {
        questions = questions.sort((a, b) => {
            return userResponse.answerSequence.indexOf(a) - userResponse.answerSequence.indexOf(b);
        });
    }

    const k = 4; //where reference should be made to dropdown item


    const vectors = kmeans.vectorizeResponses(responses);
    const cluster = await kmeans.clusterize({ vectors, k });
```

Any help on how I should go about doing this would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
This is part of a project I am working on, so my knowledge of node/express/javascript is primitive.